# C/C++ OpenCV video processing

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Good day everyone! So currently I'm working on a project with video processing, so I decided to give a try to OpenCV. As I'm new to it, I decided to find few sample codes and test them out. First one, is C OpenCV and looks like this:

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) {

CvCapture* capture = 0;
IplImage *frame = 0;

    if (!(capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0)))
    printf("Cannot initialize camera\n");

cvNamedWindow("Capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

while (1) {

    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
    if (!frame)
        break;

    IplImage *temp = cvCreateImage(cvSize(frame->width/2, frame->height/2), frame->depth, frame->nChannels); // A new Image half size

    cvResize(frame, temp, CV_INTER_CUBIC); // Resize
    cvSaveImage("test.jpg", temp, 0); // Save this image
    cvShowImage("Capture", frame); // Display the frame
    cvReleaseImage(&temp);
    if (cvWaitKey(5000) == 27) // Escape key and wait, 5 sec per capture
        break;
}

cvReleaseImage(&frame);
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);

return 0;
```

}

So, this one works perfectly well and stores image to hard drive nicely. But problems begin with next sample, which uses C++ OpenCV:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <string>

using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat edges;
    //namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
        cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_RGB2XYZ);
        imshow("edges", edges);
    //imshow("edges2", frame);
    //imwrite("test1.jpg", frame);
        if(waitKey(1000) >= 0) break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

So, yeah, generally, in terms of showing video (image frames) there is practically no changes, but when it comes to using im**** functions, some problems arise.

Using **cvSaveImage()** works out nicely, but the moment I try to use **imwrite()**, unhandled exception arises in regards of 'access violation reading location'. Same goes for **imread()**, when I'm trying to load image.

So, the thing I wanted to ask, is it possible to use most of the functionality with C OpenCV? Or is it necessary to use C++ OpenCV. If yes, is there any solution for the problem I described earlier.

---

Also as stated [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_drawing_functions.html?highlight=imwrite), images initially are in BGR-format, so conversion needed. But doing BGR2XYZ conversion seems to invert colors, while RGB2XYZ preserve them. Examples:

[images](http://www.mediafire.com/?3clzv7qifqpnc8v)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV Image Processing — C++ vs C vs Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2278228/11343)

Comment: Please show us the code that causes exceptions.

Comment: @Seckin Savasci, when I uncomment `//imwrite("test1.jpg", frame);` line, it cause exception.

Comment: @Monceber what about `imread()`?

Comment: Something like this: `Mat img = imread("test.jpg");`, I tried both with extension and without it - it still causes exception

Comment: @Monceber I updated my answer it looks like a Color problem. Try using `imread` and `imwrite` with BGR images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or is it necessary to use C++ OpenCV?

No, there is no necessity whatsoever. You can use any interface you like and you think you are good with it (OpenCV offers C, C++, Python interfaces).

For your problem about `imwrite()` and `imread()` :

> For color images the order channel is normally Blue, Green, Red , this
>   is what imshow() , imread() and imwrite() expect

Quoted from [there](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_drawing_functions.html?highlight=imwrite)

Comment: But the problem here is that it doesn't write or read images at all, but shows them correctly. If images were saved, but haven't been displayed correctly, than it would be problem with color channels. How am I supposed to change image's order of the color channels, if it have been loaded yet?

Comment: I tried just now to convert image from BGR to RGB before saving, used `cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2RGB);`, but exception is still there(

Comment: In the second code snippet in my question there are two calls (one commented) to imshow(), and both of them output taken frame to new window.

Comment: @Monceber BTW your first conversion is problematic there, You should use BGR2XYZ rather then RGB2XYZ

Comment: and now I'm confused...[here](http://www.mediafire.com/?3clzv7qifqpnc8v) I've made some screenshot for results of images... it's screenshot, so still no saving(
Normal refers to image without any conversions.

Comment: @Monceber please add thumbnails of your images in the question so anyone can see in the question context.

Comment: Can't really put thumbnails due to restrictions, so I left link to the archive.